# Swift 5; pushViewController is not working

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller

I'm testing Swift and I created a table list to show JSON data, now I would like to show details for each cell, clicking on it, into a new View Controller.

Testing the App I got the click on the cell but I don't see the new View.

This is the code capturing the click into the **ViewController.swift**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource 
  {
  
  private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero,
                            style: .grouped)
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                   forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return table
}()

 private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero,
                            style: .grouped)
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                   forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return table
 }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   
    parseJSON()
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
  }

  ....

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.selectedImage = "images/logo_2-mini.png"
        print("Click \(indexPath)   " + vc.selectedImage!) // I see it!
    
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) // I don't see it
    }
  }
}
```

This is the **DetailViewController**

```
import UIKit

 class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
 var selectedImage: String?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Pre")

    if let imageToLoad = selectedImage{
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
    print("ok")
    }
 }
}
```

I'm too newbie with swift! Can you help me here?

Comment: are you sure that the ViewController is a part of navigation stack?

Comment: *self.navigationController?.viewControllers*  looks empty...

Comment: "Looks empty"? No, better asked (more explicit) : Is `self.navigationController` nil ?

Comment: Yes, it is *nil*

Comment: Please embed your view controller in navigation controller

Comment: into *func viewDidLoad()?* Can you help me? I'm too nob with swift...

Comment: It's not a "Swift question", it's a architecture issue. Do you want a NavigationController: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller ? Or not? Only a NavigatioNController can push, else, it's `present()`. If so, look how to embed your ViewController into one.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, this is helpful. In my case, I created a table using JSON but I'm not able to add this view into the *navigation controller*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the `DetailViewController` you should change your code to

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController else { return }
    
    vc.selectedImage = "images/logo_2-mini.png"
    print("Click \(indexPath)   " + vc.selectedImage!) // I see it!
    
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
  }
```

This way you don't need to embed your `ViewController` into a navigation controller.

Also, I've created the `storyboard` variable since I don't see its declaration in your code.